# Unable to exclude dependency from another dependency in gradle 8

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle, mockserver

I'm getting this error:

> LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/casi2/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mock-server/mockserver-junit-jupiter-no-dependencies/5.15.0/40fd1649b4faff31363e100994bcb0ece8ead3cc/mockserver-junit-jupiter-no-dependencies-5.15.0.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerFactory
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/casi2/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mock-server/mockserver-junit-jupiter-no-dependencies/5.15.0/40fd1649b4faff31363e100994bcb0ece8ead3cc/mockserver-junit-jupiter-no-dependencies-5.15.0.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerFactory

In this `gradle.build` file,I tried to remove the `org.slf4j` dependency from my test:

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

testImplementation ('org.mock-server:mockserver-junit-jupiter-no-dependencies:5.15.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
```

But has no effect. Most posts I found are for old gradle versions.
What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the exclude from the junit dependency to the spring-boot dependency, as that is the one that is transitively bringing in slf4j.

```
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}

testImplementation('org.mock-server:mockserver-junit-jupiter-no-dependencies:5.15.0')
```

(took the liberty of adding a version number to the spring-boot dependency to make it work for me)

You can find out where a dependency is coming from using the [dependencyInsight](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#dependency_insights) task. In this case, I used `./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration testRuntimeClasspath --dependency org.slf4j:slf4j` and it told me that the spring-boot dependency was the one adding slf4j.